# Issue trying converting object to numeric

Tags: python, pandas

Im new to python so apologies for any dum qa in advanced,
Im tring to import a csv as data frame to pandas, do some 'df.groupby' (base on 'mean'), and to merge with other data frames,
the problem is that the values for the 'mean' are taken as an object :
Plant           object
Component        int64
PerUnitPrice    object >> that's what I'm talking about
dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):

I did try to convert using '.astype(float)' - got an error 
and with :
price_['PerUnitPrice'] = pd.to_numeric(price_['PerUnitPrice'],errors='coerce') 
that worked partially ->> it  set all the values bigger than 999 as Nan, at least that what I think it did

here are some lines from the csv that I'm importing:

---

[csv lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78wfH.png)

Comment: Have you tried to use thousands="," as argument to the read_csv() method to indicate the thousands separator ?

Comment: Don't describe the code, share the code; don't screenshot the data, provide a text sample of data. Once you do that, people will be able to help you instead of having to guess at what the problem is.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message(s).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the reading in of the data from .csv.  Looking at the image of the .csv you shared, there are thousand separators (commas) in the PerUnitPrice column (which are causing the column to be parsed incorrectly).

In your `pd.read_csv` call, set `thousands=True`, and specify the `dtype` with a dictionary, as in [the documentation for read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).  In your case, I think you'll want to use `{'Plant' : str, 'Component' : str, 'PerUnitPrice' : float}`.

A tip in debugging this sort of issue is to use [the `info()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) of a `pd.DataFrame` to check the dtypes, size, and non-null values of a DataFrame.

Comment: thanks for the help, the (thousands="," ) did the trick, great flatform (StackOverflow) and great helping guys, cheers

Comment: Hi, the attached link is looping back to my thread, did I miss something ?

Comment: @Eraz my apologies, here is the correct link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers